# How to convert a list into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a `list` of objects:

```py
['fb_ads_sm', 'Active', '18 hr ago', '23', 'sm_sg13', 'Pending', '12 hr ago', '0', ...]
```

How do I convert this into a dictionary where the keys are the 1st and 5th elements and the values are the 2nd and 6th elements?

```py
dictionary = {'fb_ads_sm': 'Active', 'sm_sg13': 'Pending', ...}
```

Comment: Assuming that pattern continues, do you mean something like `dict(zip(l[::4], l[1::4]))`?

Comment: it works for the given input..would it work for a longer list with say 100 elements ?

Comment: Yes, of course, if the pattern holds. For a *really* long `l` you might not want to materialise the two lists `l[::4]` and `l[1::4]`, but 100 elements is not very much in the scheme of things.

Comment: how do i access first and 3rd element and make it a dictionary

Comment: Have you tried adapting the information you already have to that need? It seems trivial.

Comment: yeah tat was dumb from my end ..got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use dict comprehension with list slicing

```
a = ['fb_ads_sm', 'Active', '18 hr ago', '23', 'sm_sg13', 'Pending', '12 hr ago']
{k: v for k, v in zip(a[::4], a[1::4])}
```

OR

```
dict(zip(a[::4], a[1::4]))
```

Output

```
{'fb_ads_sm': 'Active', 'sm_sg13': 'Pending'}
```

Comment: The `zip` gives you an iterator of tuples, so you can pass it straight to `dict`.

Comment: how do i access first and 3rd element and make it a dictionary ?

Comment: @LeoArad indices are *zero*-based.

Comment: zip(a[::4], a[2::4]) that should. @jonrsharpe  Tnx alot for the note.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def Convert(a): 
    it = iter(lst) 
    res_dct = dict(zip(it, it)) 
    return res_dct 
           
lst = ['fb_ads_sm', 'Active', '18 hr ago', '23', 'sm_sg13', 'Pending', '12 hr ago'] 
print(Convert(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method: data is your actual list.

```
dict_list = {}
for i in range(0, len(data)-1, 4):
    dict_list[data[i]] = data[i+1]
```