# How can I adjust the list to have some elements positioned on the same index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, position

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
info = ['385395982', '3.1', 'This is dummy text', '3843955682', '2.0', 'This is also dummy text', '248298493', '4.2', 'Another dummy text for you']
```

As you can see, the list includes this information: timestamp, rating and some text. Each of the element is appended to the list. I would like to be able to access all timestamps at index 0, ratings at index 1, and texts at index 2. How should I modify the list in order to achieve that?

My code:

```
class Scraper():
  review_information = []
  review_date = ''
  review_rating = ''
  review_content = ''
  
  def __init__():
    ...
    for contribution in review_json.get('contributions',[]):
      self.review_date = contribution.get('sortTimestamp', '')
      self.review_rating = contribution.get('rating', '')
      self.review_content = contribution.get('text', '')
      self.review_information.append(self.review_date)
      self.review_information.append(self.review_rating)
      self.review_information.append(self.review_content)

  def parse(self):
    for info in self.review_information:
      item['review_date'] = self.review_information[0]
      item['review_rating'] = self.review_information[1]
      item['review_content'] = self.review_information[2]
```

Bottom line, I would love to have all timestamps at index 0 so that in parse method I can access them with `self.review_information[0]` (and the same for rating and content).

The desired output of the list should be something like this:

```
In [16]: info[0]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[16]: ['385395982']
         ['384395562'] 
         ['248298493']

In [17]: info[1]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[17]: ['3.1'] 
         ['2.0'] 
         ['4.2']

In [18]: info[2]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[18]: ['This is dummy text'] 
         ['This is also dummy text'] 
         ['Another dummy text for you']
```

So that when I call the `info[0]` in the for loop, I get one timestamp at the time, not all timestamps at once. Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question already has answers here: [How to convert a list into a dictionary in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62872399/7414759)

Answer (score 1):

this will let you access all your entities using indices as a list

```
info = [info[::3], info[1::3], info[2::3]]
```

**Output:**

```
In [16]: info[0]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[16]: ['385395982', '3843955682', '248298493']

In [17]: info[1]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[17]: ['3.1', '2.0', '4.2']

In [18]: info[2]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[18]: ['This is dummy text', 'This is also dummy text', 'Another dummy text for you']
```

Comment: This seems helpful, but I realized it is not what I am looking for. With your example each record in the database is populated with entire list, when in fact I need each record to be populated with just one entry from the list. Each record should haveTimestamp, Rating and Text. What I am getting now is the same data for all records.

Comment: it's not clear what you want. can you include the result how do you want your `info` list to look like after doing all operations?

Comment: I included the desired output in the initial post. Let me know if it is clear now or not

Comment: I said `so that when I call the info[0] in the for loop, I get one timestamp at the time, not all timestamps at once.` `so that` refers to this situation as desired output, not something that is already happening.

Comment: do you want `info[0]` to give just `385395982`?

Comment: Yes, in one iteration of the for loop. Then in the next iteration of the for loop, I want the info[0] to give 3843955682, and finally in the last iteration 248298493. Does it make sense?

Comment: may I ask how do you plan to access the ratings and the text?

Comment: If it is possible the way I imagined it, each iteration of the for loop would assign value from info[1] to rating, and value from info[2] to text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217794/discussion-between-vishal-singh-and-amabeat-30).