# Convert a string inside a list to a list by removing newline character and removing first and last character, in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

I have a **list** and i trying to convert it into a dictionary:

```
temp_list = ['ads_sm\nActive an hour ago\n3,416,227\nm_sg13\nActive a day ago\n0']
```

I need to convert it into a cleaner **list**, after removing all **\n** characters and replacing it with a comma and removing all ' character at start and end,
so that i can save it as a **dictonary**

```
temp_list = [ads_sm,Active an hour ago,3,416,227,m_sg13,Active a day ago,0]
```

the **dictionary** should look like :

```
{'ads_sm': 'Active an hour ago ', 'm_sg13': 'Active an hour ago'}
```

My code till now is ,which is giving me an **empty dictionary**:

```
temp_list = ['ads_sm\nActive an hour ago\n3,416,227\nm_sg13\nActive a day ago\n0']
words = [w.replace('\n', ',') for w in temp_list]
status_dictionary = dict(zip(words[::4], words[1::4]))
print(status_dictionary)
```

Comment: Why is there no `'3,416,227'` and `'0'` in the final dictionary? Plus, that slicing on a one element list makes no sense.

Comment: You would like to `split` on `\n`, wouldn't you?

Comment: '3,416,227' and '0': i dont need them ..dont mind if they are there in the final dictionary

Comment: **split** on **\n** yes

Comment: Should the keys be read from the list or are the names fix? Are the value always the second and the second to last elements?

Comment: This question already has answers here: [How to convert a list into a dictionary in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62872399/7414759). **Why do you ask again?**

Comment: I had to convert it into a cleaner list and edit option was unavailable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a way:

```
temp_list = ['ads_sm\nActive an hour ago\n3,416,227\nm_sg13\nActive a day ago\n0']
splitedlist=[val for val in temp_list[0].splitlines() if not all(i.isdigit() for i in val.replace(',',''))]
dct={k:val for k,val in zip(splitedlist[::2],splitedlist[1::2])} 
#Same as dict(zip(splitedlist[::2],splitedlist[1::2]))
```

Output

```
dct
{'ads_sm': 'Active an hour ago', 'm_sg13': 'Active a day ago'}
```

Comment: @Anti_cse51 Thanks for accepting, I will ask you the same thing that DineshKumar asked you: Please upvote if it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you.

```
temp_list = ['ads_sm\nActive an hour ago\n3,416,227\nm_sg13\nActive a day ago\n0']
sp_list = temp_list[0].split("\n")
x = zip(sp_list[0::2], sp_list[1::2])
print(dict(x))
```

Output:

```
{'ads_sm': 'Active an hour ago', '3,416,227': 'm_sg13', 'Active a day ago': '0'}
```